# React Native MainActivity {org.example.app.dev/org.example.app.MainActivity} does not exist after upgrade to Expo 47

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, android-manifest

I have a very odd issue I was not able to google out. It might seem as a duplicate, but is not. What basically happens is that when I build my app via terminal, I get an error message:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=org.example.app.dev/org.example.app.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.example.app.dev/org.example.app.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

The odd thing about is that the package name is doubled, spearated with a forward slash, which I haven't seen anywhere on the net. The first part is the part with suffix of our flavour "dev".

The issue with it is that after the build, the app does not start itself, but after manual tap on its icon it starts normally.

It started to happen when I had to migrate our app from Expo 45 to 47 and due to bad initial setup and migrations since Expo 39-ish, it was easier to start the project from scratch and migrate files one by one. The whole src, assets and even iOS was easy, but the Android part is really weird.

I tried:

- Moving and/or changing and/or adding the intents in AndroidManifest.xml
- Changing the applicationId
- Triple-checked our product flavors and buildTypes
- Checked the folder and file hierarchy
- Followed instructions about uninstalling the app, rebuilding project in Android Studio, invalidation all packages and resetting the project etc.

Here is the `AndroidManifest.xml` where the intents are specified. The package name has been replaced by a placeholder value.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="org.example.app">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
  <application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="${APP_NAME}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
  >
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATE_URL" android:value="https://exp.host/@llifmobile/mobile"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="47.0.0"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.ENABLED" android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_CHECK_ON_LAUNCH" android:value="ALWAYS"/>
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_UPDATES_LAUNCH_WAIT_MS" android:value="0"/>
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="${APP_NAME}" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:exported="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen">
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="example" android:host="app"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

The `build.gradle` file has changed a lot after the upgrade, but nothing suggests what could cause the duplicates.

The error was not present before and what I am expecting is for the app to open directly after the build. I am not sure how it would behave in production as it works when you manually open it, but I want it to be resolved before the time to push it even to staging comes.

I will be happy for any kind of advice or lead, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our AndroidManifest.xml was missing this intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

in the `.MainActivity`

so the whole block looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:exported="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="somename" android:host="app"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What is rather interesting that the `AndroidManifest.xml` worked like that for over a year and stopped working only after the Expo upgrade and SDKs and other things with it.

I hope this will help someone in the future.